# SDL2: Is SDL_GetMouseState() thread-safe?

Tags: sdl-2

Is `SDL_GetMouseState` function thread safe?

And in the example of `SDL_GetMouseState`, the `SDL_PumpEvents`, which is known to be thread-unsafe, is used. If `SDL_GetMouseState` is thread-safe, do I have to use `SDL_PumpEvents` which is thread-unsafe with it to make it properly working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code of this function is:

```
Uint32
SDL_GetMouseState(int *x, int *y)
{
    SDL_Mouse *mouse = SDL_GetMouse();

    if (x) {
        *x = mouse->x;
    }
    if (y) {
        *y = mouse->y;
    }
    return mouse->buttonstate;
}
```

And `SDL_GetMouse` just returns address of static global variable. Hence, there is nothing unsafe with it, but there is no atomicity.

However events are processed separately. If you don't prcess events, mouse structure wouldn't update and `SDL_GetMouseState` will give you outdated values. Documentation explicitly states you should call `SDL_PumpEvents` only in graphics thread (the one that initialised graphics system).

Worst case scenario is you reading vales from `SDL_GetMouseState` while other thread updates it. You could read old value, new value, or even a mix of two (e.g. x from new but y from old).